# How can a django 1.6 app recover from database outage?

Tags: django, psycopg2

I have a django 1.6 application with a long running daemon process, that need to handle database outages gracefully. I am using the `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` engine.

What I have tried so far is that after I have handled a DatabaseError and logged it, I try to close the database connection, wait for some time and let the next transaction create a new connection.

That is not working out well for me. The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from core.models import User
from django.db import close_connection
from django.db.transaction import atomic
from time import sleep

@atomic(savepoint=False)
def do_something():
    u = User.objects.get(username='brian')
    sleep(3)
    u.set_unusable_password()
    u.save()

try: do_something()
except Exception as e: print 'A:', e

try: close_connection()
except Exception as e: print 'B:', e

sleep(3)

try: do_something()
except Exception as e: print 'C:', e
```

If the database connection goes down during the sleep call in the first transaction, and recovers during the sleep call between the two transactions, I see this:

```
A: connection already closed
B: connection already closed
C: The outermost 'atomic' block cannot use savepoint = False when autocommit is off.
```

If I use `savepoint=True` instead, the output looks slightly different:

```
A: connection already closed
B: connection already closed
C: connection already closed
```

What I found so far is that the first exception is raised by `__exit__` in the `atomic` decorator. Presumably this is masking an exception raised by `set_unusable_password`.

The second exception is raised when `close_connection` try to call `abort`.

The final exception is raised by `__enter__` in the `atomic` decorator before it even tries to communicate with the database server.

What do I need to do more than calling `close_connection()` in order to clean up old state, such that I can establish a new connection to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `close_connection` is deprecated. I found this in the source:

```
def close_connection(**kwargs):
    warnings.warn(
        "close_connection is superseded by close_old_connections.",
        PendingDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

Using `close_old_connections` instead of `close_connection` doesn't change anything. The problem behaved exactly the same. The source of `close_old_connections` did look promising though:

```
def close_old_connections(**kwargs):
    for conn in connections.all():
        # Remove this when the legacy transaction management goes away.
        try:
            conn.abort()
        except DatabaseError:
            pass
        conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
```

Turns out the problem shows up in `conn.abort()` which apparently is only there to support legacty transaction management. It seems from the code that exceptions from `conn.abort` can be safely ignored. But in my case `conn.abort` doesn't raise a `DatabaseError` rather it raises `InterfaceError`.

If I copy the implementation of `close_old_connections` into my own code and modify it to handle both `DatabaseError` and `InterfaceError`, my symptoms do go away.

I found one [known bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22556), which is somewhat related to my problem.

After looking into what actually happens inside `close_connection` and `close_old_connections` I came up with the following lines, which as far as I can tell do the right thing:

```
try: django.db.connection.abort()
except django.db.utils.Error: pass
django.db.connection.close()
```